# MS Access VBA Stored Procedure return value to text box

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm having one of those moments and have forgot how to return a value from a SQL SP to a textbox?

I'm calling a SQL SP from MS Access 2013 using the below code and this returns the value to a listbox no problem - what property do I use to return the SP value to a text box?

Working Code:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qMasterPass")
     .SQL = "exec SKULookup " & txtSKUSearch
     Set Me.List38.Recordset = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

Non-working code - what should be where the ? are:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qMasterPass")
     .SQL = "exec SKULookup " & txtSearch
     Set Me.Text7.?????? = .OpenRecordset
End With
```

Thanks

Comment: are you trying to call a stored proc in SQL-Server from ms-access ?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: You really should be using parameterized queries here instead of building up a string and executing it. This is wide open to sql injection.

Comment: I'm executing the above from an Access FE.  The paramater is passed via the txtSearch - how does this leave it open?

Comment: For the question at hand...what you mean by "return the SP value"??? Does the stored procedure return a value? You really should NOT be using return like this. It is intended to indicate a status of execution. If you want values returned you should use output parameters.

Comment: It is open to injection because txtSearch could contain malicious values. That is the nature of sql injection. Your procedure obviously is receiving a parameter but you are executing dynamic sql to call it.

Comment: ah ok. the text box has a validation rule on it if that helps to limit input?

Comment: can I enter something like 'test or 1=1' in txtSearch ? If yes what would that result be ? This is classic sql injection

Comment: No. Any validation can be easily defeated. Why not just parameterize it and do it the right way? It is so simple to parameterize sql that not doing it is negligence. But this is totally off topic. See my previous question about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: in summary a table has two fields.  I pass a value - that exists in field 1 and I want SQL to return the value from field 2.  If there is a quicker\better way then please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your recordset has 1 record with 1 column, you could do this:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qMasterPass")
     .SQL = "exec SKULookup " & txtSearch
     Me.Text7.Text = .OpenRecordset.Fields(0).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
With CurrentDb.QueryDefs("qMasterPass")
     .SQL = "exec SKULookup " & txtSearch
     Me.Text7.Value = .OpenRecordset.Fields(0).Value
End With
```